# Method get not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I create my own ServiceProvider to send param form ENV when initiation class:

```
class InstagramServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../config/config.php' => config_path('instagram.php'),
    ]);
}
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('instagram.client', function ($app) {
        return new InstagramClient([
            'apiKey' => $app['config']->get('instagram.clientId'),
            'apiSecret' => $app['config']->get('instagram.clientSecret'),
            'apiCallback' => $app['config']->get('instagram.redirectUri'),
            'scope' => $app['config']->get('instagram.scope'),
       ]);
    });
}
public function provides()
{
        return array('instagram.client');
}
}
```

And I can't get data from config? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has a function built specifically for this job called `config()`. You can use it as follows:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('instagram.client', function ($app) {
        return new InstagramClient([
            'apiKey' => config('instagram.clientId'),
            'apiSecret' => config('instagram.clientSecret'),
            'apiCallback' => config('instagram.redirectUri'),
            'scope' => config('instagram.scope'),
       ]);
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could use a bracket notation like so:

```
$app['config']['instagram']['clientId']
```

For more information see documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: You could also use `$app['config']['instagram']['clientId']` etc.

Comment: Ahh, great one! I'll add that. :-)